# fstream.read() Not Reading Anything At All

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream

I'm trying to read the first line of an MP3 file (I edited this mp3 file to contain the text "I'm an MP3" right at the beginning of the file).

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream mp3;
    mp3.open("05 Imagine.mp3", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    /*mp3.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int lof = mp3.tellg();
    cout << "Length of file: " << lof << endl;
    mp3.seekg(0, ios::beg);*/

    //char ch;
    //cout << mp3.get(ch) << endl;

    char* somebuf;
    while(mp3.read(somebuf, 10)) //Read the first 10 chars which are "I'm an MP3 file".
    {
        //cout << somebuf;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, that is crashing. At some point it didn't crash, but it didn't print anything when I did cout << somebuf. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The first ten characters would be "I'm an MP3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never allocated anything for `somebuf`:

```
char* somebuf;
```

therefore, it doesn't point anywhere.

```
char* somebuf = new char[11];
somebuf[10] = '\0';          //  Not sure if it is necessary to null-terminate...
while(mp3.read(somebuf, 10)) //  Read the first 10 chars which are "I'm an MP3 file".
{
    //cout << somebuf;
}


//  and free it later
delete [] somebuf;
```

Alternatively:

```
char somebuf[11];
somebuf[10] = '\0';          //  Not sure if it is necessary to null-terminate...
while(mp3.read(somebuf, 10)) //  Read the first 10 chars which are "I'm an MP3 file".
{
    //cout << somebuf;
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to `delete[]` it afterwards :)

Alternatively, you could use a cstring: `char somebuf[10] = {};`. I added the `= {}` to initialise the string elements to null characters, which isn't required here but it's good practice in general.

Comment: @thekashyap He wants to print it out. I'm not sure if it needs to be null-terminated.

Comment: Ah, I see you beat me to it :P

@thekashyap: You need 11 characters so that you can insert a "null character" at the end of the string. If your string does not have a null character, you won't be able to output it or use functions such as `strcpy`, `strlen` etc as they cannot determine where the string ends if it doesn't have a null character to terminate it.

Comment: after you added `somebuf[10] = '\0';` it makes sense.. :)

Comment: @ChrisParton though you're right in general, I usually expect everything (read/write/buffers/copy/contcat/...) abt a file opened in binary mode to be strictly controlled by programmer him/herself.. like use `strncpy`

Comment: @thekashyap: Yeah that's fair enough. It's always a good idea to use `strncpy` over `strcpy` etc to avoid buffer overflows and the like; I was just using those functions as examples.

Comment: DANG. I feel like a complete newb right now hahahaha. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, you definitely need to null-terminate the string manually. My program was printing some trash after the "I'm an MP3 file" string because I didn't null-terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the buffer:

```
char somebuf[10];
    while(mp3.read(somebuf, 10)) //Read the first 10 chars which are "I'm an MP3 file".
    {
        //cout << somebuf;
    }
```